# How to restrict new row insertion when dataGridView Check box Column is clicked?

Tags: c#

I have a DataGridView with checkBoxColumn.When I clicked on checkBoxCell of CheckBoxColumn it adds New Row to dataGridView.But I do not want to add row on click event or checked chang event of DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn.
Please some one suggest me how to do this. 
Thanx in Advance.

Comment: Make 'AllowUserToAddRows' property of DatagridView as 'false'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After binding the rows set AllowUserToAddRows property to false.
Ex:

```
MyDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are clicking the check box on a new created row (normally the last row in your GridView)
This row has not jet been attached to your underlying datasource, but will be attached as soons as you change the value of your checkbox cell.

At this stage I don't think there is a way to prevent it (unless you prevent the user from adding new rows at all).
You could handle DefaultValuesNeeded() to set the checkbox to an appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

In design view right click on the data grid view. There will be a check box with description "Enable Editing". Please uncheck it. Then there wont be any new row added on  click of the checkbox